# Common area of a square and a Bézier curve

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Find the common area of a region from a quadratic Bézier curve $$B(t)=(1-t)[(1-t)P_0 + t P_1] + t[(1-t)P_1 +t P_2], 0 \leq t \leq 1$$ (Where $$P_0, P_1, P_2$$ are 2-dimensional vectors representing points) to line segment P0 P2 and a square $$x_s - 0.5 \leq x \leq x_s + 0.5, y_s - 0.5 \leq y \leq y_s + 0.5$$

EDIT:
So when the Bezier Curve is a line the area = 0.
Let's assume the curve is not a line and $x_1 \ne \frac{x_0+x_2}{2}$ and $y_1 \ne \frac{y_0+y_2}{2}$:
Let $A = d_0-2d_1+d_2$ and $B = d_1 - d_0$ where $d_n$ is either $x_n$ or $y_n$. (d is x) Let $$f(x)=\frac{-B \pm \sqrt{\max(0,B^2-A(x_0-x))}}{A}$$$$y(x)=f(x)^2(y_0-2y_1+y_2)+f(x)2(y_1-y_0)+y_0$$
y(x) is the formula for y of x with branches being the same constant when the result is complex which will not matter when calculating the area because we can subtract areas below those branches and they will cancel out.
The antiderivative for this formula is
$$(y_0−2y_1+y_2)I_2+(2y_1−2y_0)I_1+y_0x$$
where
$$I_1=\frac{\pm 2(B^2-A(x_0-x))^{\frac{3}{2}} - 3ABx}{3A^2}$$
$$I_2=\frac{3(B^2-A(x_0-x))^2 \mp 8B(B^2-A(x_0-x))^{\frac{3}{2}}+6B^2Ax}{6A^3}$$ See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804289/int-frac-2-x-1-2-x-0-pm-sqrt-max0-2-x-1-2-x-02-4x-0-2-x-1/4804532#4804532)

Y becames constant when $x=x_0-\frac{B^2}{A}$
The common points of the top/bottom of the square can be found by subtituting $x_n$s with $y_n$s and vice-versa and $x$ with $y$ of the sides. So finally we have 5 points and the formula to calculate area under the curve it looks like this on a graph:[image: graph]
I can see a pattern for different parameters but I still haven't figured out an elegant method for determining which ranges of x has which function inside/over/below.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Googling what Points arę on the curve and what arent

Comment: I think I need to find an integral somehow

Comment: This is a quadradic Bezier curve so it's a parabola. The tangent lines at $P_0$ and $P_2$ intersect at $P_1$ so these are easy to sketch in a practical sense. I'd recommend you draw a few, check how they relate to your square, and then see if you can use your geometric intuition to set up the equations.