# $\int(\frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{\max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)})^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)...$

Tags: calculus

Hello I need to find this monster: $$\int(\frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{\max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)})^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{\max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)}) (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0$$

to find a definite integral. Idk how to even start. Maybe some simplification. Do you know how to solve it? What technique to use? The function should be is continous and always real. Here's a graph for $(x_0, y_0) = (10, 5), (x_1, y_1) = (2, 7), (x_2, y_2) = (8, 3)$: [image: graph]

Comment: There is no $dx$ or $dy$ or anything in there.

Comment: Ah sorry of course dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:
$$\delta=x_1-x_0$$
$$\Delta=x_0-2x_1+x_2$$
$$a\dot{-}b:=\max(0,a-b)$$

$\dot{-}$ is the [monus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monus).

The integral became

$$\int\left(\frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{\max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)}\right)^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-(2 x_1 - 2 x_0) \pm \sqrt{\max(0, (2 x_1 - 2 x_0)^2 - 4(x_0 - 2 x_1 + x_2)(x_0 - x)})}{2 (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)} (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\int\left(\frac{-2\delta \pm \sqrt{(2 \delta)^2 \dot{-} 4\Delta(x_0 - x)}}{2 \Delta}\right)^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{(2 \delta)^2 \dot{-} 4\Delta(x_0 - x)}}{2 \Delta} (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\int\left(\frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \dot{-} \Delta(x_0 - x)}}{ \Delta}\right)^2 (y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)+ \frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \dot{-} \Delta(x_0 - x)}}{\Delta} (2 y_1 - 2 y_0) + y_0\mathrm{d}x$$

$$(y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)\int\left(\frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \dot{-} \Delta(x_0 - x)}}{ \Delta}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x+ (2 y_1 - 2 y_0)\int\frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \dot{-} \Delta(x_0 - x)}}{\Delta}\mathrm{d}x  + \int y_0\mathrm{d}x$$

---

$$(y_0 - 2 y_1 + y_2)I_2+ (2 y_1 - 2 y_0)I_1  + y_0x$$

Where:

$$I_1=\int\left(\frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \dot{-} \Delta(x_0 - x)}}{ \Delta}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pm 2\left(\delta^{2}\dot{-}\Delta\left(x_0-x\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-3\delta\Delta x}{3\Delta^{2}}$$

$$I_2=\int\left(\frac{-\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 \dot{-} \Delta(x_0 - x)}}{ \Delta}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3\left(\delta^{2}\dot{-}\Delta\left(x_0-x\right)\right)^{2}\mp 8\delta \left(\delta^{2}\dot{-}\Delta\left(x_0-x\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+6\delta^{2}\Delta x}{6\Delta^{3}}$$

---

Here a [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f7wl2aodew?lang=it) where you can check that the accounts are correct and in case you need to modify the variables (note that I couldn't put the $\pm$ so I put a parameter $s\in\{0,1\}$ which is used to calculate a $(-1)^s$)